# ionic ios build failed. Type 'CustomEvent' is not generic

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

When I run the command `ionic cordova build ios` I am getting the below error:

```
Running app-scripts build: --platform ios --target cordova
[12:54:28]  build dev started ... 
[12:54:29]  clean started ... 
[12:54:29]  clean finished in 7 ms 
[12:54:29]  copy started ... 
Config file "/Users/<user_name>/Documents/Working Folder/<project_name>/config/copy.config.js" not found. Using defaults instead.
[12:54:30]  deeplinks started ... 
[12:54:33]  deeplinks finished in 3.10 s 
[12:54:33]  transpile started ... 
[12:54:52]  typescript: node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component.d.ts, line: 41 
            Type 'CustomEvent' is not generic. 

      L40:  onError: EventEmitter<any>;
      L41:  onProgress: EventEmitter<PDFProgressData>; 
      L42:  pageChange: EventEmitter<number>;

[12:54:52]  typescript: node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component.d.ts, line: 42 
            Type 'CustomEvent' is not generic. 

      L41:  onProgress: EventEmitter<PDFProgressData>;
      L42:  pageChange: EventEmitter<number>;               
      L43:  src: string | Uint8Array | PDFSource;

Error: Failed to transpile program
    at new BuildError (/Users/<user_name>/Documents/Working Folder/<project_name>/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
    at /Users/<user_name>/Documents/Working Folder/<project_name>/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:159:20
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at transpileWorker (/Users/<user_name>/Documents/Working Folder/<project_name>/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:107:12)
    at Object.transpile (/Users/<user_name>/Documents/Working Folder/<project_name>/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:64:12)
    at /Users/<user_name>/Documents/Working Folder/<project_name>/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:109:82
[12:54:52]  copy finished in 23.56 s
```

Before building, I had

- Removed `node_modules`, added again with `npm i`.
- Removed and added ios platform using `ionic cordova platform remove ios` and `ionic cordova platform add ios`.
- Upgraded `cordova-ios` from `4.4` to `5.1.0`

**My ionic info:**

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 5.1.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim    : 8.0.2 
    Node       : v10.0.0
    npm        : 5.6.0 
    OS         : macOS
    Xcode      : Xcode 13.1 Build version 13A1030d 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: It looks like the error is coming from your PDF Viewer node module. Have you tried removing it and rebuilding? Also, a lot of your framework is out of date. Are you able to update it?

Comment: Commenting those 2 lines created the build successfully. But not sure how that will affect the app. Still looking for a valid answer.

Comment: The issue is happening because your framework is out of date, most likely a TypeScript mismatch with the PDF Viewer node module.